# JQuery Hide/Show on Scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery.  I'm trying to write a script that will hide the div "box" and all children.  When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the div "box" and all children display. For time's sake, we'll say the children are "chamber1", "chamber2" and "chamber 3".

when I hide "box", it only removes that div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#box").hide();
});
```

Apologies for lack of code, but I'm having trouble understanding this lesson and I can't find an exact example of what I'm trying to do through my internet searches.

Thank you!

Comment: `#box` are id selector, so you cant use that using multiple, just use `.box` class selector, and try to put the html also, so we can check the html code.

Comment: try jquery .appear() it will show your div when it is in the viewing area of the browser

Comment: omg why are you implementing like this for?

Comment: @DJDJ23 Check out the Answer below it would help you i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you to hide the box when you reach the bottom of the page, you javascript should be as follows:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("scroll", function(){
     if ( window.scrollMaxY == window.scrollY ) {
        $("#box").hide();
     }
   })
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
  <div>Chamber 1</div>
  <div>Chamber 2</div>
  <div>Chamber 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The div is hidden on
   $(document).ready(function() {

I need it to re-appear when I scroll down the page.

Comment: @DJDJ23 instead of hide make it show: $("#box").show();

Comment: This is what solved my problem.  Sorry for the late response.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the div has id "box". If you're working with a div of class "box" then you would use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").hide();
});
```

Comment: Also, what you're doing here will hide the div only. If you need to hide the children, give them a separate id and have them hide rather than hiding the div. Check the examples on this API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Ok, I got this to work, finally.  Yes, it was a problem with my naming conventions between class/id.  Now for the magic to make it re-appear when I scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you and would be better to understand. A good explantion is given below here with demo.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight() == $(document).outerHeight()) {
    //Script for activity on reaching bottom of document
    $("#box").fadeOut();
  } else // optional
  {
    $("#box").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fee;
}
#box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  background: lightblue;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 210px;
}
#box > div {
  margin: 5px;
  background: #F33636;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>

<div id="box">
  Box
  <hr>
  <div class="chamber1">
    Chamber 1
  </div>
  <div class="chamber2">
    Chamber 2
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/kap5yykc/)**

> You can play around with Fiddle Link.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. Going to try to implement it to my page.  Will report back shortly.